# Select all gifs in the page via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to create a list with all the `<img>` elements in my page that are gifs (and not jpegs, pngs, etc.). Right now I am doing it like this:

```
var imgs = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementsByTagName('img') );
imgs = imgs.filter(function(img){ return img.src.endsWith(".gif") })
```

Is there a shorter alternative using pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with [attribute value ends with selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```
var allGifs = document.querySelectorAll('img[src$=".gif"]');
```

`querySelectorAll` returns a collection, so if you want an array, you'll still need the `Array.prototype.slice` trick or `Array.from` (ES2015 but shimmable), etc. (Also, the collection it returns is not "live" like the one `getElementsByTagName` returns.)

---

The same selector can be used with jQuery.<sup>Adding for reference for jQuery people</sup>

```
$('img[src$=".gif"]')
```